# keeping libraries at correct place when multiple pythons are installed

Tags: python, opencv

QUESTION1:I have 3 versions of pythons installed in my mac.

1.Apple supplied one       (2.7.1) (/usr/local/bin)

2.Macports installed one   (2.7.3) (/opt/local/bin)

3.and one from python.org  (2.7.3) (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin)

I would like to add external modules like opencv,pygame.I have no idea where the installed binaries are going and when I try to import them I get this "no module found" error.How to make macports installed python and python.org installed python use opencv module or some other external modules.

QUESTION2:How to add external libraries to pydev in eclipse

Comment: How are you installing the binaries? You can find out where they went with something like `/usr/local/bin/python -c 'import cv; print cv.__file__'` for each of the possible `python` commands.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your interpreter in eclipe (either the first time, or by going to the preferences menu) you need to select an interpreter (don't use the auto-configuration).

Eclipe will use that interpreter, and libraries relative to it.  If you install new libraries, just go back to prefrences>pydev>interpreter, and click "Apply" on the screen where the interpreters are selected (you don't need to change anything, but new libraries will be scanned for).

I recomend using ports, if possible, since you'll most likely find everything you need there and won't have to deal with any manual installation of modules.